# How can i auto-fill a form field based on the title of an attached document?

Tags: python, html, django, forms

This is my form:

[image]

models.py:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    Document_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Document_Name')
    Date = models.DateField()
    Client = models.ForeignKey(ClientDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    File = models.FileField()
    Filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Document_name
```

upload.html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-left: 16px">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

forms.py:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = '__all__'
```

What I want to happen is when I choose a document to attached e.g. test1.pptx, I want the Filename field to auto populate with that name (test1.pptx)

Answer (score 0):

Add ID to the fields

```
class Document(models.Model):
    Document_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Document_Name',attrs={'id': 'file-name'})
    Date = models.DateField()
    Client = models.ForeignKey(ClientDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    File = models.FileField(attrs={'id': 'file-input'})
    Filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Document_name
```

then in the template

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-left: 16px">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
  $('#file-input').on("change", function(){

       $("#document-name").val($(this).val());
 });


</script>
```

This will work just parse the name and everything will work like a charm

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'
Do I have to use widgets?

Comment: Alright, but currently there are Id's assigned to each field when i run it. My DB is in postgresql. Do i still need to assign the ids in models.py?

id_Filename
id_File

Comment: Ooh if you have Id already assigned just replace the values in the javascript with the fields values don't change your form then

Comment: Tried it but still no luck, The field isn't getting populated

Comment: Check the updated js in the answer, im pretty sure is some js issue... 
Do you have Jquery imported? in your html